# Android Email Intent Not Sending Attached File

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I have created an application that sends an email with a recording, When the intent is fired and email is chosen as the app to send the attachment, you can see that there is an attachment but the attachment is not delivered.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//Mime type of the attachment (or) u can use sendIntent.setType("*/*")
sendIntent.setType("audio/3gp");
//Subject for the message or Email
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Recording");
//Full Path to the attachment
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileName));
//Use a chooser to decide whether email or mms
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've got the same problem whith an image, even with the "file://" at the beginning. Heve you found another way to make it work?

Comment: I found the issue, my file was private, so the mail application couldn't read the file. It now works fine

Comment: @D4r7h How did you make your file "not private"? with 'file.SetReadable (true);'??
I also tried to move the file to ~ folder, with no luck. I have a txt file that gets correctly sent.
Can you give me a hint, pls?

Answer (score 11):

I figured it out, you need to make sure that your uri has "file://" in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with API level 24, you cannot use "file://" URIs for passing files between packages. Instead, you should implement [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) and pass the file using it.

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.yourdomain.yourapp.fileprovider", file);
```

The good thing about FileProvides is that you don't need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (for API level 21 and above).

The best description as at [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28874567/2870459) or in that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

UriAttachment does not longer works. You have to use FileProvider. But you have to work a little bit to make it work.

This video explains it perfectly  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYvV4m-N9oY&t=535s[Share](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYvV4m-N9oY&t=535s%5BShare) Photos & Files Using FileProvider][1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYvV4m-N9oY&t=535s).

But, it didn´t work for me, I had to do something else. I had to replace res/xml/file_paths.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths>
     <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

As it is described in an answer to this question: [FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root). You should use only the lines you need to make it work.

I was fighting a long time with this until I found a proper way to do this.