# How to send an email along with image automatically attached to it?

Tags: android, email, email-attachments, android-camera-intent

I want to send an email along with an image that is recently captured from my camera app. The problem is that I am unable to attach the image automatically to the email. So, what should I do so that the image gets automatically attached to the email?

CameraActivity.java

```
    public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        File image;
        private boolean isUserClickedBackButton = false;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        dispatchPictureTakeAction();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });


            imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.capturedImage);
            }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void dispatchPictureTakeAction() throws IOException {
        Intent takePic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePic.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = createPhotoFile();
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(HomeActivity.this, "com.example.brainyfools.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePic.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePic, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    String currentPhotoPath;
    String imageFileName;

    private File createPhotoFile() throws IOException {
        String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imageFileName = "JPEG_" + name + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
}
```

ComplaintActivity.java

```
public class ComplaintActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complaint_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        floatingActionMenu = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionMenu);
        fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent imgSrc = getIntent();
                String imgUrl = imgSrc.getStringExtra("imgurl");
                File file = new File(imgUrl);
                if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xyz123@gmail.com"});
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, details);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                intent.setType("application/image");
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078099/android-intent-for-sending-email-with-attachment) for this question.Try to get uri of the captured image and send it.