# can't attach file with an email

Tags: android, email, filepath, email-attachments

hello i am trying to attach a text file to send it with an email but when opening the email interface it says file does'not exist while it's really exist on the phone storage here's the code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"MyMail@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "report gps location");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folderName/file.txt"));
            try
            {
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } 
            catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: could I see how did u create the file?

Comment: final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folderName/" );

Comment: final File myFile = new File(dir, fileName + ".txt");

Comment: do u write anything in there? is 'fileName' value 'file'?

Comment: yes i its a parameter the i pass a value to it

Comment: if the file has contents and nothing else fails... maybe you´re sending the wrong uri. Use a File instead of an string such as this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078099/android-intent-send-an-email-with-attachment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email from internal storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072895/email-from-internal-storage)