# FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to take a picture with camera, but I'm getting the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.marek.myapplication, PID: 6747
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.marek.myapplication/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170228_175633_470124220.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
    at com.example.marek.myapplication.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.java:56)
    at com.example.marek.myapplication.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:22)
    at com.example.marek.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.marek.myapplication.fileprovider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Java:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while saving picture.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.marek.myapplication.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

I was searching whole day about this error and trying to understand `FileProvider`, but I have no idea what this error message tries to tell me. If you want more info/code, write me in the comment.

Comment: Ran into the same issue.  Found this solution to get a basic FileProvider setup going using a minimal github example project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103567/2162226  .  It provides steps for which files to copy over (without making changes) into a local standalone project

Comment: This issue is now fixed in Delphi 10.4: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-26950

Answer (score 609, accepted):

Your file is stored under `getExternalFilesDir()`. That maps to `<external-files-path>`, not `<files-path>`. Also, your file path does not contain `images/` in it, so the `path` attribute in your XML is invalid.

Replace `res/xml/file_paths.xml` with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="/" />
</paths>
```

---

**UPDATE 2020 MAR 13**

Provider path for a specific path as followings:

- `<files-path/>` --> `Context.getFilesDir()`
- `<cache-path/>` --> `Context.getCacheDir()`
- `<external-path/>` --> `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
- `<external-files-path/>` --> `Context.getExternalFilesDir(String)`
- `<external-cache-path/>` --> `Context.getExternalCacheDir()`
- `<external-media-path/>` --> `Context.getExternalMediaDirs()`

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: ok, I added external-files-path, but i have still the same error :/ There is maybe more bugs. I'm using emulator android device, do I have to create that folder or something?

Comment: @Pivoman: If you are getting the exact same error ("Failed to find configured root" with the same general path)... the only explanation that I can think of is that you are using an old version of the Android Support libraries. Make sure that you are using a current version (e.g., `25.2.0`). Otherwise, I do not know what to tell you.

Comment: I have newest versions of all libraries.

Comment: "'path' attribute should be defined" we are missing here path in the configuration.

Comment: I was having a problem with multiple paths on Android 5. Left only one path, instead of 2.

Comment: I received one crash report (out of 50-100 devices, I think) that is identical to this. `<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <external-files-path name="extfiles" path="."/>
</paths>` The `path="."` is what I found in my own research to stay at the top level. If you go through FileProvider more closely, you'll see that the path read from XML gets canonicalized. My best guess is that `ContextCompat#getExternalFilesDirs` returned null @line 616 (v26.0.1), so a PathStrategy wasn't registered. This occurred on Huawei device.

Comment: Instead of using <external-files-path  i tried <external-path and it worked.

Comment: @androidguy did you find a solution?

Comment: @tanaytandon Not in a satisfactory sense. I put `FileProvider.getUriForFile` in try, catch IllegalArgumentException and treat it as if the device storage is unavailable. It's quite possible that it will consistently fail on the affected device.

Comment: I find it completely bizarre that you complain that `path` is set to `images/` which is not in the file path, and then proceed to set `path` to something else which is not in the file path??

Comment: @Nimitz14: That was [somebody else's edit to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42516202/revisions). I will revert that momentarily.

Comment: @CommonsWare why did you revert fix with "path=..." ? It seems to be mandatory.

Comment: @DmitriyPavlukhin: First, it is not mandatory. If you are seeing a complaint in Android Studio, that is an over-zealous Lint check. Second, even if you want `path`, the right answer would be `path="/"` in this case, not `path="my_images"` as the edit had.

Comment: @CommonsWare it would be amazing if you'd add this comment to your answer,  look at the most popular comment here)

Comment: <external-files-path/> worked for me. <external-path/> only worked on my emulator

Comment: This worked for me     <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>

Comment: I have got this, but it is a bit strange it should be storage/0/Android.../ but  ```Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/3915-9DD5/Android/data/com.my.packagename/cache/8d914ae4-c1a1-4c64-b2ab-ee454b43bc0c/Status Quo - In The Army Now.mp3```

Comment: @nAkhmedov: `FileProvider` does not support removable storage, and that filesystem path looks like it is from removable storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for reply? what a approach do you suggest for me? My FileProvider works with external-cache dir folder.

Comment: @nAkhmedov: Either do not work with removable storage, or write your own `ContentProvider` to serve the files from removable storage.

Comment: FYI: I have the correct configuration (as per this answer) but still receive crash report form some Huawei devices (see @androidguy comment)
More info about Huawei devices and this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895579/fileprovider-geturiforfile-error-on-huawei-devices

Comment: Fortunately I don't need to pay special attention to Huawei as my app is not popular in Asia, in fact only published in a few countries there and hardly any users.

Answer (score 360):

This may resolve everyones problem:
All tags are added so you don't need to worry about folders path.
Replace res/xml/file_paths.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
  <external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
  <cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="." />
  <external-cache-path
    name="external_cache"
    path="." />
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

**EDIT: 1st June 2021**

We should use only specific path which we need.
Try alternate path on your own and use which you needed.

**See Accepted answer for more information**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516202/4498813

Comment: Yes, you right bro. This is most common working solution for all related problems.

Comment: But why are you giving access of every folder?

Comment: If someone stuck and can not find solution then this generic solution may work for them at list. and also you don't need to worry about folders path if you are accessing more from storage. @BugsHappen

Comment: Simple solution ... but for this brilliant!
I used a provider then I entered the user possibility to change the destination directory ... nothing worked anymore because at that point the provider should be dynamic .... you saved my day!

Comment: used this solution and the code started working. Removed unnecessary code by testing which one of these was working

Comment: Already upvoted. @Mitul I need your one more help.  What is the permission should I give if I am trying to access  file in the root path of apk for below Android 24 ? I get error Unable to open '/data/user/0/com.ibm.appcenter/files/sample.com.android.apk': Permission denied . 
Basically I am trying to install apk downloaded in a path /data/user/0/com.ibm.appcenter/files/
Above Android 24 it works as I am using file provider.

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar Just download your file in context.cacheDir folder and access over their.

Comment: Great  worked for me, as a new learner it made me realise I wasn't getting from external files but cache

Comment: I still get the exception on some devices, even with these settings..

Comment: @JohnDoe Please give more details like - exception/error, your codes & Mobile model details. If you wants to fix it.

Comment: @Kartik what tests did you performed to find which one is working?

Comment: Also , for everyone, @commonsware mentions in their latest update (in the selected answer) that each of these tags to different functions. so what is the java part of this answer ?

Comment: PLEASE don't do this. Follow the accepted answer and do not add a blanket allow-all rule in your app. File access security is part of the framework for a reason

Answer (score 95):

Got similar problem after enabled flavors (dev, stage).

Before flavors my path resource looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
    name="my_images"
    path="Android/data/pl.myapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

After added android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
in Manifest appId was pl.myapp.dev or pl.myapp.stage depends on flavor and app started crashing.
I removed full path and replaced it with dot and everything started working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks! How you came up with '.' notation ?

Comment: @antygravity can you please provide reference/documentation of this solution ?

Comment: Are there any negative consequences of this solution?

Comment: Worked for me , Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! The only solution that worked

Comment: @geekoraul Based on my understanding the reason the "." annotation works is because that the external-file path is already specified by the "<external-path>" tag. The dot annotation can also be written here as "./" which means current directory specified by "<external-path>" (root of "external-path") ref -> https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles

Answer (score 62):

I am sure I am late to the party but below worked for me.

```
<paths>
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: This was the final step to get my code working as well! Thanks.

Comment: Awesomeeeeee! I was trying to access the `no_backup` folder but I couldn't find a way to expose it in the FileProvider XML file. Thanks! Doing this fixed my issue!

Comment: This was what I needed, to allow FileProvider to access the `no_backup` folder.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It worked like a charm after nothing else did!!

Comment: This didnt cause a crash. but my image was not attached.

Answer (score 51):

If you are using internal cache then use.

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: thanks,my situation : I want installed an app which saved in /data/data/pkg_name/files,so my correct configure as follow:

<files-path
        name="files"
        path="/"/>

Answer (score 41):

Lost 2 weeks trying to find some solution... If you arrive here after try everthing above:

1 - **Verify if your tag provider are inside tag application**

```
<application>

    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.Pocidadao.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>

</application>
```

**2 - If you try a lot paths way without success, then test with this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
  <external-path name="external" path="." />

  <root-path name="root" path="." />
  <files-path name="my_images" path="/" />
  <files-path name="my_images" path="myfile/"/>
  <files-path name="files" path="." />

  <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <external-path name="images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-path name="my_images" path="." />
  <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.companyname.yourproject/files/Pictures" />
  <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.companyname.yourproject/files/Pictures/" />

  <external-files-path name="images" path="Pictures"/>
  <external-files-path name="camera_image" path="Pictures/"/>
  <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="my_images" />

  <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />

</paths>
```

Test this, if camera works, then start eliminate some lines and continue testing...

**3 - No forget verify if camera are actived in your emulator.**

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Is it necessary to remove other paths?

Answer (score 25):

Be aware that external-path is not pointing to your secondary storage, aka "removable storage" (despite the name "external"). If you're getting "Failed to find configured root" you may add this line to your XML file.

```
<root-path name="root" path="." />
```

See more details here [FileProvider and secondary external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318116/fileprovider-and-secondary-external-storage)

Answer (score 20):

This confusing me a bit too.

The problem is on "path" attribute in your xml file.

From this document [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)
'path' is a subdirectory,
but in another document (camera/photobasics) shown
'path' is full path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

I just change this 'path' to full path and it just work.

Answer (score 19):

I would be late but I found a solution for it.Working fine for me, I just changed the paths XML file to:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: For me this in `provider_paths.xml` gives an inspection warning "Element root-path is not allowed here".

Comment: This gives warning ..check it at once and post corrective answer.

Answer (score 15):

Check how many storages your device offers - sharing files from secondary storage is not supported. Look at `FileProvider.java` source (from *support-core-utils 25.3.1*):

```
            } else if (TAG_EXTERNAL_FILES.equals(tag)) {
                File[] externalFilesDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
                if (externalFilesDirs.length > 0) {
                    target = externalFilesDirs[0];
                }
            } else if (TAG_EXTERNAL_CACHE.equals(tag)) {
                File[] externalCacheDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(context);
                if (externalCacheDirs.length > 0) {
                    target = externalCacheDirs[0];
                }
            }
```

So, they take only the first storage.

Also, you can see that `getExternalCacheDirs()` is used to obtain list of storages through the `ContextCompat` interface. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDirs()) for its limits (it's told to not recognize USB Flashes for example). Best is to make some debug output of list of storages from this API on your own, so that you can check that path to storage matches the path passed to `getUriForFile()`.

There's already a [ticket assigned](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37125252) (as for 06-2017) in Google's issue tracker, asking to support more than one storage. Eventually, I found [SO question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318116/fileprovider-and-secondary-external-storage) as well.

Comment: This in-depth answer should be getting more upvotes. Thank you for searching out what external storage FileProvider actually recognizes.

Answer (score 15):

I have spent 5 hours for this..

I have tried all the methods above but it depends on the what storeage your app currently using.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#GetUri

Check the documentation before trying the codes.

In my case 
since `files-path` sub directory will be `Context.getFilesDir()`.
The funky thing is it `Context.getFilesDir()` notes one another subdirectory.

what I am looking for is

### `data/user/0/com.psh.mTest/app_imageDir/20181202101432629.png`

```
Context.getFilesDir()
```

returns 
`/data/user/0/com.psh.mTest/files`

so the tag should be

....`files-path name="app_imageDir" path="../app_imageDir/" ......`

Then it works!!

Comment: Thanks for referring to documentation. It led me to the correct answer. In my case my file was saved with `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and I was supposed to provide the path  with `<external-path>` tag instead of `<files-path>`

Comment: Thank you for this specific answer on files-path. It helped a lot. :)

Comment: Yes it works!!! the key point is to specify the ".." at the beginning of the path, like this path ="../myDirectory/"

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly!
The official documentation doesn’t say at any time that you need to put ".." for folders starting with "/app_myfolder/"

Answer (score 11):

Change your `main/res/xml/provider_paths.xml`

> From

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="images/" name="myimages" />
    <external-path name="download" path="download/"/>
</paths>
```

> To

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 9):

None of this worked for me. The only approach that works is not to declare an explicit path in xml. So do this and be happy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="." />
</paths>
```

Here too has a excelent tutorial about this question:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZxRTKvtfnY&t=613s

Answer (score 8):

My issue was that I had overlapping names in the file paths for different types, like this:

```
<cache-path
    name="cached_files"
    path="." />
<external-cache-path
    name="cached_files"
    path="." />
```

After I changed the names ("cached_files") to be unique, I got rid of the error. My guess is that those paths are stored in some HashMap or something which does not allow duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

This Worked for me as well.Instead of giving full path i gave path="Pictures" and it worked fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths>
  <external-files-path
    name="images"
    path="Pictures">
  </external-files-path>
 </paths>
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did to solve this -

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
        </provider>
```

filepaths.xml (Allowing the FileProvider to share all the files that are inside the app's external files directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="files"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

and in java class -

```
Uri fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),"com.mydomain.fileprovider",newFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends what  kind of storage you want to do, INTERNAL or EXTERNAL

for EXTERNAL STORAGE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="my_images" />
</paths>
```

but for INTERNAL STORAGE, be careful with the path, because it uses getFilesDir() method
which mean that your file will be located in the root directory for the app ("/")

```
  File storeDir = getFilesDir(); // path "/"
```

So your provider file must be like this:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: All examples assume that user is using external storage. I needed help with internal storage and it took hours to find this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> I had the same problem, I tried the below code for its working.

**1.Create Xmlfile : provider_paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="myfile/"/>
</paths>
```

**2. Mainfest file**

```
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.ril.learnet.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
 </provider>
```

**3.In your Java file.**

```
      File file =  new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "myfile");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String  destPath = file.getPath() + File.separator + attachmentsListBean.getFileName();

               file mfile = new File(destPath);
                Uri path;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                {
                    path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", mfile );
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    path = Uri.fromFile(mfile);
                }
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

none of the above worked for me, 
after a few hours debugging I found out that the problem is in `createImageFile()`, specifically `absolute path` vs `relative path`

I assume that you guys are using the official Android guide for taking photo. https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

```
    private static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Take note of the `storageDir`, this is the location where the file will be created. So in order to get the absolute path of this file, I simply use `image.getAbsolutePath()`, this path will be used in `onActivityResult` if you need the Bitmap image after taking photo

below is the `file_path.xml`, simply use `.` so that it uses the absolute path

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

and if you need the bitmap after taking photo

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If nothing helps and you are getting the error

```
failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/...
```

then try changing some line like:

```
File directory = thisActivity.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to:

```
File directory = new File(thisActivity.getFilesDir(), "images");
```

and in the xml file:

```
<files-path name="files" path="." />
```

which is weird, since the folder I access is `/images`.

Comment: Switching from .getDir to .getFilesDir helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem might not just be the path xml.

Following is my fix:

Looking into the root course in `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile()`:

```
    public File getFileForUri(Uri uri) {
        String path = uri.getEncodedPath();

        final int splitIndex = path.indexOf('/', 1);
        final String tag = Uri.decode(path.substring(1, splitIndex));
        path = Uri.decode(path.substring(splitIndex + 1));

        final File root = mRoots.get(tag); // mRoots is parsed from path xml
        if (root == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find configured root for " + uri);
        }

        // ...
    }
```

This means `mRoots` should contains the tag of requested uri. **So I write some code to print `mRoots` and tag of uri, and then easily find the tags do not match**.

**It comes out that setting provider authority as `${applicationID}.provider` is a stupid idea**! This authority is so common that might be used by other providers, which will mess up the path config!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error `Failed to find configured root that contains...`

The following work around resolves my issue

**res/xml/file_paths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="media" path="." />
</paths>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="[PACKAGE_NAME]"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
         <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
         </meta-data>
</provider>
```

**ActivityClass.java**

```
void shareImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.slappstudio.pencilsketchphotomaker", selectedFilePath));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,getString(R.string.string_share_with)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Android official document says file_paths.xml should have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <external-path name="my_images"    
        path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

> But to make it work in the latest android there should be a "/" at the end of the path, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <external-path name="my_images"    
        path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures/" />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following change in xml file_paths file worked for me.

```
 <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures"/>
 <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**My Problem Was Wrong File Name**:
I Create `file_paths.xml` under res/xml while resource was set to `provider_paths.xml` in Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="ir.aghigh.radio.fileprovider"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

I changed `provider_paths` to `file_paths` and problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

If your file path is like /storage/emulated/0/"yourfile"

you just need modify your FileProvider xml

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external" path="." />
</paths>
```

then call this function when you need share file

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                            "com.example.myapp.fileprovider",
                            file);
                    sharingIntent.setType("*/*"); // any flie type
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share file"));
```

it works on android M ~ Pie

Comment: It's works! But can you explain why we use path="." instead of path="DCIM", "Pictures"...?

Comment: @Hoang Lam The difference is whether you need to specify a directory, in my example you can access all

Answer (score 1):

The Answer from @**CommonsWare** is great.

But in my case, I had to add multiple paths.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <files-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, I met this problem. **If you have already set the provider in your manifest and you still have this error——just add `<root-path name="root" path="." />` in your xmls file."** I need to do some thing to the file in USB device and add this line work for me. I hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I see that at least you're not providing the same path as others in file_paths.xml.
So please make sure you provide the exact the same package name or path in 3 places including:

- `android:authorities` attribute in manifest
- `path` attribute in file_paths.xml
- `authority` argument when calling FileProvider.getUriForFile().

Answer (score 0):

- For **Xamarin.Android** users

This could also be the result of not updating your support packages when targeting Android 7.1, 8.0+. Update them to [v25.4.0.2+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView/25.4.0.2) and this particular error might go away(giving you´ve configured your file_path file correctly as others stated).

---

> Giving context: I switched to targeting **Oreo** from **Nougat** in a
>   [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) app and taking a picture with the [Xam.Plugin.Media](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media)
>   started failing with the above error message, so updating the packages
>   did the trick for me ok.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the policy or behaviour regarding the `path.xml` file changed between Support Library 26 and 27. For capturing a picture from the camera, I saw the following changes:

- With 26, I had to use `<external-path>` and the full path given in the `path` argument.
- With 27, I had to use `<external-files-path>` and only the subfolder in the `path` argument.

So what specifically worked for me with Support Library 27 as the `path.xml` file was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="camera_image" path="Pictures/"/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Friends Try This**

> In this Code

1) How to Declare 2 File Provider in Manifest.

2) First Provider for file Download

3) second Provider used for camera and gallary

**STEP 1**

```
     <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

**Provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<files-path name="apks" path="." />
</paths>
```

**Second Provider**

```
     <provider
        android:name=".Utils.MyFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities"
        tools:ignore="InnerclassSeparator">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
    </provider>
```

**file_path.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path name="storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**.Utils.MyFileProvider**

Create Class **MyFileProvider** (only Create class no any method declare)

**When you used File Provider used (.fileprovider) this name and you used for image (.provider) used this.**

**IF any one Problem to understand this code You can Contact on rp1741995@gmail.com i will help you.**

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="" />
</paths>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can improve the quality of your answer by adding an explanation ('Try this code, because...'). This will help others understand _why_ they should use your code.

Comment: path cannot be empty

Comment: I think we should not down vote him, he is new on SO! All these downvotes block him from using SO! We can comment him and let him know how to help! Atleast he tried to help someone, he did not wrote all the informations because he was so new in the platform!

Answer (score -2):

You need to change the xml file file_paths.xml from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <exeternal-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.marek.myapplication/files/Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Although you have copied your answer from above, it is not properly done. Please correct the typing mismatch in your answer.

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena Please add a link to the comment that has a copy of this comment. Please compare the date. I don't found any comments with my recommendation (set 'path' attribute to correct string) on Mar 6 2019 at 14:36 and added the answer. If the answer has already been copied, I will remove the comment.

Answer (score -2):

You need to ensure that the contents of your file_paths.xml file contains this string => "/Android/data/com.example.marek.myapplication/files/Pictures/"

From the error message, that is path where your pictures are stored. See sample of expected

files_path.xml below:

```
<external-path name="qit_images" path="Android/data/com.example.marek.myapplication/files/Pictures/" />
```