# Having trouble displaying PDF file in my Application

Tags: android, pdf, android-7.0-nougat

I was able to successfully download the PDF file from the server(Web API) using the following code

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    File file;
    File outputFile = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    int count;
    string filename = "xxx.pdf"
    try {
        //output path would be "/data/user/0/package.ofapplication/files/folder/"
        file = new File(interface.getFileDirectory(),"folder"); 

        if (!file.isDirectory()) file.mkdirs();

        //output would be "/data/user/0/package.ofapplication/files/folder/xxx.pdf"
        outputFile = new File(file, filename);

        URL url = new URL(getUrlMethod());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        .......other
        .......related
        .......downloading codes

        //this would return "/data/user/0/package.ofapplication/files/folder/xxx.pdf"
        return outputFile.getPath();
    }
```

Now I'm getting an error when I'm trying to view the PDF file using the following code in Android.

```
// output path would be /data/user/0/package.ofapplication/files/folder/
File pdfFile = new File(pdfPath);

Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

//this is the part where im getting an error
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getActivity(), this.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",pdfFile), "application/pdf");
```

The error message I'm getting from the above code is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains /data/data/package.ofapplication/files/folder/1.pdf

Can somebody please help me on this I'm crying and searching for hours right now and still can't find a way. I also tried this link but I'm still having the same error

> [FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root)

Note: my provider_path below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: have you tried to use 'files-path' instead of 'external-path'?

Comment: not yet, but ill try it right now

Comment: @HareshChhelana it worked! please post it as your answer hahaha you made my day

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to store the file on the `internal storage` and defines path element on XML as the `external storage` like `<external-path`, So try to change path element on XML as the `internal storage`:

```
<external-path
```

TO

```
<files-path
```

More info. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: Accept answer and upvote which help other users get the correct solution for same.