# FileProvider IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android

I try to open pdf file.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.interactivegroup.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

    </provider>
```

my pdf files in Download folder on the Android device

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="files" path="." />
<root-path name="pdfs" path="/storage/emulated/0/Download" />
```

open file method

```
File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/Киоски.pdf");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SendActivity.this,  "com.interactivegroup.android.fileprovider", file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    SendActivity.this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

And i always catch this Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /Download/Киоски.pdf
```

I cannot find enough explanation what's wrong.

Sorry for my broken English((((

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the file_path.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <external-path name="files" path="."/>
      <external-path name="pdfs" path="Download/" />
  </paths>
```

and try:

```
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.interactivegroup.android.fileprovider", newFile);
```

Comment: it changed nothing (