# TakePhotoAsync Camera not open

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, montemagno-media.plugin

I follow very tutorials and answers here in site without success. Spending lot time.

Using `Media.Plugin`, method `TakePhotoAsync()` not open the camera (Genymotion 9.0 API-28 | device samsung j7 prime. android 8.0).

`PickPhotoAsync()` working wonderful.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.Pocidadao.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

**file_path.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
  <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.companyname.Pocidadao/files/Pictures" /> 
</paths>
```

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    try
    {
...
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        UserDialogs.Init(this);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION HERE => "+ex);

...

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

**METHOD.XAML.CS**

Problem in >>var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions..
But not erros, exception, etc...

```
async void TakePhoto(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Ops", ":( Nenhuma câmera detectada.", "OK");
                    return;
            }

            var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

            if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Camera, Permission.Storage });
                cameraStatus = results[Permission.Camera];
                storageStatus = results[Permission.Storage];
            }

            if (cameraStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted && storageStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {

        //===HERE IS THE PROBLEM, READ METHOD BUT NOT OPEN CAMERA! NOT ERRORS, NOT EXCEPTION, NOTHING===
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    SaveToAlbum = true,
                    //Directory = "Sample",
                    //Name = "test.jpg"
                });


                if (file == null)
                    return;

                await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

                if (MyImage.Source == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MyImage.Source == null ==> OK");
                }

                MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    file.Dispose();
                    return stream;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Permissions Denied", "Unable to take photos.", "OK");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION HERE =: "+e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: After lot days, this save my life: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55883100/4654957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code, this error was by the `file_path.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.companyname.Pocidadao/files/Pictures" /> 
</paths>
```

If I change Path of `my_images` to 
`<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />` ,you can take a Photo as normal

Here is my demo.

https://github.com/851265601/TakePhotoDemo

Here is GIF of my demo.

[image]

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to mark it as an answer( please click the “✔” at the right of answer). It will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: I thank you for having tested my code. But I am getting the following exception: EXCEPTION HERE =: System.ArgumentException: Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Because this I was using that way: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119942/mediaplugin-argument-exception-unable-to-get-file-location

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I was missing this portion of code in my manifest, please check that too.

```
<application android:label="XXX.Android" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```