# Take photo with Camera and save in FileProvider

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I need help on taking a Photo in Android (in Java) using a FileProvider.
I wrote the Android tutorial (+ much more) on taking photos, so I ended up with the following situation:
My manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

My res/xml/file_paths.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path
            name="schede_images"
            path="Android/data/com.android.example/files/Pictures" />
    </paths>
```

Then, the method for callying the Camera Intent:

```
    String currentPhotoPath;
    @OnClick(R.id.startCamera)
    public void startCamera(View v) {
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "provaprovaprova");
        if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
            boolean isCreated = imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            if (!isCreated) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Errore storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        try {
            File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".fileprovider", image);
            currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Util.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.ACTION_FOTO_CAPTURE));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Finally, the onActivityResult:

```
if (requestCode == Util.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.ACTION_FOTO_CAPTURE)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

The problem is that, in the method startCamera, on the 14th line:

```
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".fileprovider", image);
```

I have an IllegalArgumentException:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.example, PID: 25184
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.example/files/Pictures/IMG_20191113_152356_376811633.jpg
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
```

Comment: check below answer

Comment: duplicate [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root) i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove
path = "Android/data/com.android.example/files/Pictures"  to path = "/"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <external-files-path
        name="schede_images" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: Thank's, it worked well. In addition I had to add this for supporting old api (19 in my case), to avoid permission problems:
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", uri));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }`