# Android Illegal Argument Exception, cant find configured root that contains storage/(SD Card Directory)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to open a video file stored in my device using the default media player(VLC).
Code:

```
 public void startPlay(View view) {
        String name = "VideoName.mkv";
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.packagName.AppName",
                new File("storage/[sd card directory]/Videos/"+name));
        Log.d("PATHVAR", path.toString());
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setType("video/*");        
          startActivity(shareIntent);

}
```

On the other hand, when I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`, it doesn't throw any errors.
Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.packageName.AppName"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

Provider paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <external-path name="external" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
    <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
    <files-path name="files" path="." />
    </paths>
```

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/6262-6133/Videos/VideoName.mkv
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
        at com.packageName.AppName.MainActivity.startPlay(MainActivity.java:201)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14222) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7091) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Any idea why this is happening? I've set up the necessary permissions and am able to create a text file in internal storage. I've searched around for a solution to this but most of them are using internal storage, not the sd card.
Thanks.

Comment: you have to define fileprovider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root)

Comment: @karan , ive looked at that but unfortunately the person is using the internal storage, not sd card

Comment: @karan how do I define it?

Comment: you can see which path you need to use in the answer by commonsware sir