# Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.x Media Plugin async problem

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created a new Xamarin Forms App with the media plugin (via NuGet on VS 2019) and used a part of the samples-code to take photos. The images are created correctly. Problem is the code after PickPhotoAsync is never executed (Same with the complete sample from github):

```
pickPhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
      {
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
          DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
          return;
        }
         var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                      {
                          PhotoSize =  Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
                    
                      });


        if (file == null)
          return;

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
          var stream = file.GetStream();
          file.Dispose();
          return stream;
        });
      };
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: What's your XF version,i test your codes in version 4.8.0.1364 and 4.8.0.1534,they both work.

Comment: It is XF 4.8.0.1534, I am developing on Samsung Galaxy Tab SM-T585

Comment: Did you try to run it on other devices ?

Comment: I tried to run the sample on a Huawei Media Pad, but the App crashes imediatly. I did this with current and older version of Xamarin Forms - result is the same.

Comment: It's weird.It works on my side,is there any error message ?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this issue. There no other messages. Now I will setup a new project again, paste the samples code into this class and keep you informed about the results.

Comment: Ok,you could try it.

Comment: I give up: After creating a new Project it is still the same: none of the awaited functions ever returns ( CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync,  CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync).

Comment: On a different device an error comes up: It could be solved like described in [42516126](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root). With this alternative file_paths.xml everything works fine.

Comment: You could try to report it to the github of the plugin.

Comment: Your are right, I will try to do so.

Comment: Please check (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/884)

Comment: Yes,i'll keep an eye on it.