# Android App Crashes after Taking photo on real device but works on emulator

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage, android-fileprovider

I have a camera intent that takes a photo then returns back to the activity. It works fine on the emulator but on a real device, it crashes after taking the photo and accepting it.

The **error** I get on the device is this

```
Process: com.example.smartcalendar, PID: 29675
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.smartcalendar/com.example.smartcalendar.DailyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4605)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4647)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:2)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage.<init>(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.1.0:74)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage.fromBitmap(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.1.0:12)
        at com.example.smartcalendar.DailyActivity.onActivityResult(DailyActivity.java:236)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7759)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4598)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4647) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

These are the relevant code blocks

```
        Intent camintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (camintent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile;
            photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = **createImageFile();**
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occured creating the file");
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                camintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                **startActivityForResult(camintent, 101);**
            }
        }
```

That launches the **activityonresult** but before that, it calls this method to **createImageFile**.

```
String currentPhotoPath;
    private File **createImageFile()** throws IOException {
//        String currentPhotoPath;
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = **getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)**;
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = **image.getAbsolutePath()**;
        return image;
    }
```

Inside the onActivityResult, this is the code I have for now.

```
//        Bitmap takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+ BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bm));
            bm.compress(JPEG, 100, out);
            Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+ BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(decoded));
        }
```

Here is the provider in the Android Manifest

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
```

**Here is file_paths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="." />
</paths>
```

For the file_paths.xml I tried to follow this [answers' advice.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51740118/14650328)

My suspicions are that the problem lies somewhere in trying to save the photo to storage and retrieve it later as well.

Comment: Make sure that you are putting `photoFile` into the saved instance state `Bundle`, as your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground. [This sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider) is a bit old but demonstrates the basic concept. Beyond that, I recommend that you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace, not just the first line.

Comment: Do you mean in the OnCreate method?

Comment: Save it in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it either in `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.