# Android - Save a file from raw assets to external storage for others apps to access gives failed to find content root exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, android-assets

I have a **file in my raw assets** directory which I am trying to save to shared phone storage that will **allow other apps to open and view this video**.

I am able to save the file to my local app storage or to external private app storage using the following code.

```
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    // using getFilesDir() below causes this error: 
    File videoFile = new File(getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1], "talking.mp4");

    // check if we have already copied file over
    if (!videoFile.exists()) {

        try {
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.talking);
            boolean newFile = videoFile.createNewFile();
            if (!newFile) {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create file");
            }
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
            byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(data);
            os.write(data);
            is.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + videoFile, e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to copy talking.mp4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Line below 135  
    Uri uri =  FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName(), videoFile);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Problematic Line

    // type of file to view
    in.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");

    // ask some other app to deal with it
    startActivity(in);
```

**The problem is** I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains 
    /storage/1B12-3A08/Android/data/${getPackageName()}/files/talking.mp4

        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
        at ${getPackageName()}.MainActivity.btnPlayIntentClicked(MainActivity.java:135)
```

Having done a quick bit of research with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516202/4628115) and [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider), I added this to my Manifest:

```
<application ... >
    //...
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${getPackageName()}"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider> 
</application>
```

and have the following resource at `res/xml/paths.xml`:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_files" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="my_files" path="." />
    <external-path name="my_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

**Question:**

Having configured the available content root, I should be able to copy over a file from raw resources to external private storage and request Android (via implicit intent) to play the video using e.g. MX Player or VLC for Android.

What am I missing with the content root configuration? (I added both `external-files-path` and `external-path` for good measure)

---

Update after @Commonsware's answer

I changed

```
File videoFile = new File(getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1], "talking.mp4");
```

to

```
File videoFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "talking.mp4");
```

which is also just

```
File videoFile = new File(getExternalFilesDirs(null)[0], "talking.mp4");
```

But this gave the same error, but just another path prefix to the file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/${getPackageName()}/files/talking.mp4
```

*I was able to get the file the content root to work and pass the file Uri with an Intent, which gave the option of open with VLC (for Android) and a few others, problem was non of the apps could play the file. I cannot remember how I did it though*

---

**Update 2**

@BlackApps's suggestion of changing the path names in the `res/xml/paths.xml` file solved the problem

Initially I had different names, but it had not worked and didn't consider changing them back after some experimentation.

**Reason why it caused the problem:**

Content Root paths are loaded on app start via [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/compat/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.java#599) function:

```
FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(Context, String)
```

Inside, it create a cache (Map) of all paths by using their corresponding file provider paths to provide additional context (appending a path to the specified path in the `<external-file/>`,`<files-path/>`. Given the input:

```
<external-file name="some_name" path="MyAwesomeAssets"/>
```

will result in an ([external](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/compat/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.java#628)) target path (of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`) prepended to the path "MyAweomseAssets" resulting in a output path of `/storage/emulated/0/MyAwesomeAssets`.

This is then added to a cache, but in my case since I had the same name for each, it would simply override the last path i.e. FIFO approach.

So, when I am attempting to get the Uri of a file in the content roots I specified, there will only be one found, and that would be the last one defined in `res/xml/paths.xml`.

Comment: `name="my_files" ` You have three times the same name. Make them different.

Comment: @blackapps yes - that solved the issue. Had given it different names before but that didn't help either. Regardless, your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`FileProvider` does not support removable storage. Either change `getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1]` to `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, or you will need to write your own `ContentProvider` to serve the content from your desired location (or directly from assets, if you prefer).

Comment: @CybeX: `<external-files-path>` maps to `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, so it is unclear why your setup is not working. You might want to examine your merged manifest and confirm that your `<provider>` element is there and is unchanged -- if some library happens to also be using your same authority string, perhaps its metadata is getting picked up for some reason.

Comment: for the record, this is a new VM - check the manifest and provider is as shown above - I am quite puzzled.