# Android path in the Fileprovider is not recognised

Tags: android

I get this following exception for xlsx, msg and xml

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/myadress/aFile.xlsx
       at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
```

I saw several issues related but cannot find where is the error

I am reading the official documentation but do not get where can be the bug because do not understand where is going wrong

Comment: `attachment.createTemporaryFile(filesDir)` Please show the value of filesDir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/myadress/aFile.xlsx

You should serve from the `files` directory:

```
/data/data/<packagename>/files/aFile.xlsx
```

Comment: unfortunately I do not get what you mean what do you think about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52849797/12912064

Comment: Well what do you mean with `myadress'? And where is the code that we can see where the file resides?

Comment: You should use path /data/data/myadress/files/aFile.xlsx i said.

Comment: myadress is the domain of my company. and filesDir from `createTemporaryFile(filesDir)` is an SDK method from ContextWrapper Class inbuilt in android, it stays for getFilesDir(). Do I guess anyway that the link I gave could resolve the issue, I see it solved it for everyone with the same problem

Comment: `myadress is the domain of my company. ` The name of your company is irrelevant for this problem. Your name too. It should be the package name of your app. And that's what i used. Tell us full path of your file as all is unknown.

Comment: yes this the full path in the xml was 'Android/data/com.company/files/Pictures` but now I changed all with `"."`