# Open Camera Intent with filepath android 11 not working

Tags: android, android-camera

The open camera intent is not working in android 11, the app is getting crashed everytime, but the same code is tested and working in Android 6,7,8.

Below is the code --

```
private void openCameraIntent() {
        Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null){
            //Create a file to store the image
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d("IOError", ex.getMessage());

            } catch (Exception ex2) {
                Log.d("Error", ex2.getMessage());
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getPackageName()+".fileprovider", photoFile);
                pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

String imageFilePath;
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        imageFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("imageFilePath", imageFilePath);
        return image;
    }
```

Android menifest file --

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

file_paths.xml --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--change only the package name if you have change the package name of app-->

    <external-path name="my_images" path="AppName/Temp/" />

    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>

</paths>
```

What might be the changes required which i am missing. Please guide me to achieve the solution. Thank you.

Comment: what does th crash say

Comment: You should use external-files-path and not twice.

Comment: external-files-path -- tried but not working

Comment: @Raghunandan, crash says -- Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/user/0/com.abc.myapp/files/my_images/IMG_20210304_113243_5404740245023599800.jpg

Comment: @jahangiralam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root use external-files-path