# PlatformException (Failed to find configured root) when trying to share an image on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, share-plus

I want to share an Image from a url. I am using the `share_plus` and `shareFiles` method to share it.

Please check my code here:

```
final url = Uri.parse(url);
final response = await http.get(url);
final bytes = response.bodyBytes;

final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final file = File('${directory.path}/tempp.png');
await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

print(file.path);

await Share.shareFiles([file.path]);
```

I'm getting this exception

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mrblab.news_app/cache/share/tempp.png, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mrblab.news_app/cache/share/tempp.png
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:825)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:450)
    at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.getUrisForPaths(Share.java:128)
    at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.shareFiles(Share.java:69)
    at io.flutter.plugins.share.MethodCallHandler.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandler.java:42)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:984)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8149)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)
))
```

I have given `READ` and `WRITE` permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I've also created `provider_paths.xml` after seeing [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516202/14228678)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="share"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Post you provider_paths.xml and tell exact value of url. They just dont match for the used file provider. You do not need READ or WRITE permission for that path.

Comment: Should I use cache-path or anything else for getTemporaryDirectory?

Comment: Sorry i asked for url but i ment value if 'file'. Full path please.

Answer (score 0):

The location of your file does not match the paths in the xml file.

Realise that you app has two cache locations.

```
getCacheDir() and getExternalCacheDir()
```

You mixed them up.

All is in: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: How do I getCacheDir() in Flutter?

Comment: Your file is located in getExternalCacheDir(). That is ok. You only have to change the path in the xml file to use getExternalCacheDir() as now it uses getCacheDir(). This causes for the failed to find configured root message. The link i posted tells you how to take the right path. Did you read the link?

Answer (score -1):

To overcome this issue you can configure your URL in following way:

```
String imageUrl =
  "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/23/83/360_F_143238306_lh0ap42wgot36y44WybfQpvsJB5A1CHc.jpg";

// 1. Download the image to a temporary file
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
final bytes = response.bodyBytes;
final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final path = '${temp.path}/image.jpg';
final file = File(path);
await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

// 2. Share the temporary file using shareXFiles
await Share.shareFiles([path], text: 'Image Shared');
```

I hope this helps.
**Happy Fluttering!!**